# Data structure for dealing with intervals

Tags: data-structures, tree, language-agnostic, intervals

I've spotted a question and couldn't solve it:

[1 ... n^5] interval  was divided into n non-equal non-overlapped intervals.
given these intervals and their names, can anyone give me a good data structure which can answer these following queries:

1. input: integer x

   output: name of interval where x is located
2. input: two integers x,y

   output: if they are located in two adjacent intervals, then  union intervals/ new interval holds the name of the left one.
3. input: two integers x,y

   output: if they are located in the same interval [i...j], then split it into three: [i...x-1],[x....y-1],[y....j].

Comment: what about if the two values x,y are not found in adjacent intervals, but maybe there is m intervals between them?

Comment: An [interval tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) with names stored in the nodes should be able to handle this.